# Replace empty entry with previous element in associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I have following `$data` array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [match_day] => MD27
            [price] => 95.33
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [match_day] => MD28
            [price] => 97.82
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [match_day] => MD29
            [price] => 
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [match_day] => MD30
            [price] => 
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [match_day] => MD31
            [price] => 
        )
)
```

Now, my requirements is - replace empty entry of price attribute with previous price attribute.

Comment: Loop through with one variable which you assign the price if it isn't empty, otherwise you use the variable to assign it to the price. Done.

Comment: Use the `foreach()` function in PHP to loop through your array.

Answer (score 2):

No need to go for `for loop` You can try following code:

```
$result = [];
array_walk($data, function($v,$k) use (&$result){
    $result[$k] = $v;
    if(!isset($result[$k]['price']) || $result[$k]['price'] == null){
        $result[$k]['price'] = $result[$k - 1]['price'];
    }
});

print_r($result);
```

Working Demo is [Here](https://3v4l.org/EPSnk)

Answer (score 0):

Perform a foreach loop an your array, store previous price value and if the current item has empty price, use previous to replace it. Example:

```
$previous = 0;
foreach($data AS $key => $row) {
  if (empty($row['price']))
    $data[$key]['price'] = $previous;
  else
    $previous = $row['price'];
}
```